# The expectation of a Bernoulli divided by an associated sum of bernoullis

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, symmetry, bernoulli-distribution

For $i=1,\dots, k$, let $X_i \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p_i)$ be independent such that $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i > 0$. How do I evaluate the following expectation:
$$\mathbb{E} \left( \frac{X_i}{\sum_{j=1}^k X_j} \right),$$ where consider that $0/0=0$ by convention?
I see that the denominator has a [Poisson Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). When $p_1 = \dots = p_k$, numerical evidence suggests that the expectation is $1/k$; indeed this can easily be proven by symmetry. In general, numerical evidence suggests that the expectation does not evaluate to $p_i / \sum_{j=1}^k p_j$, although I'm not sure.

Comment: What about division by zero?

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks; I've updated the question using notation that I think is common

Comment: With that convention you can write $\mathbb{E}\Big[\frac{X_i}{\sum_{j=1}^k X_j}\Big] = \mathbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{1+\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^k X_j} \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i=1\}}\Big]$ and then use independence. I am not sure if there is a closed form for that evaluation though.